# My dataset lists state and county FIPS codes separately. How should I combine?

Tags: python, data, geocoding, excel, fips

I can't do a simple "concatenate" because the codes don't have leading zeroes. Are there any available APIs that I can use to geocode this data given the format? Or do I have to manipulate them so that they resemble a more typical GeoID.

[image: FIPS codes columns]

Comment: Is there a reason that the two FIPS attributes need to be dealt with as one? Where is your data from, and what are you trying to do with it? What programs are you using to achieve this? You'll want to provide as much information about your situation as possible in order to get valuable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Python method `zfill(n)` will convert an integer to an n-character string padded with leading zeros.

```
a = 1
b = a.zfill(3) #Yields '001'
```

Comment: this sounds like it will work, thank you!